# My nextjs form returns undefined on api part on file upload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I have a multipart form and i have created a route inside api, i am using some packages to handle file upload but i get undefined whenever i try to print form data inside the api middleware
I have tried tweaking a lot with the code but the online soutions just doesnt work need a better way to do it
here is the code for formmiddleware

```
import nextConnect from "next-connect";
import multiparty from "multiparty";

const middleware = nextConnect();

middleware.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  const form = new multiparty.Form();

  await form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    req.body = fields;
    req.files = files;
    console.log(fields, " files ", files);
    next();
  });
});

export default middleware;
```

code for api route

```
import formParserMiddleware from "../../../middlewares/formParser";
import nextConnect from "next-connect";

const handler = nextConnect();

handler.use(formParserMiddleware);

handler.post(async (req, res) => {
  res.json({ files: req.files, body: req.body });
});

export default handler;
```

code for form

```
<form
        method="POST"
        action="/api/book/upload"
        encType="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <label htmlFor="UploadBook__title" className={styles.UploadBook__label}>
          Title of book
        </label>
        <input placeholder="title here" name="title" id="UploadBook__title" />{" "}
        <br />
        <label
          htmlFor="UploadBook__author"
          className={styles.UploadBook__label}
        >
          Author
        </label>
        <input placeholder="Author" name="author" id="UploadBook__author" />{" "}
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="UploadBook__pdf" className={styles.UploadBook__label}>
          PDF Book (if available)
        </label>
        <input placeholder="pdf" name="pdf" id="UploadBook__pdf" type="file" />{" "}
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="UploadBook__audio" className={styles.UploadBook__label}>
          PDF Book (if available)
        </label>
        <input
          placeholder="audio files"
          id="UploadBook__audio"
          name="audio"
          type="file"
          multiple
        />{" "}
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="UploadBook__desc" className={styles.UploadBook__label}>
          Description of book
        </label>
        <input
          placeholder="Description"
          name="description"
          id="UploadBook__desc"
        />{" "}
        <br />
        <h1>Product Details</h1>
        <div>
          <span>Price</span>{" "}
          <input placeholder="if you wanna sell(rs)" name="price" /> <br />
          <span>Publisher</span>{" "}
          <input placeholder="publisher" name="publisher" /> <br />
          <span>Publish Date</span>{" "}
          <input placeholder="date of publishing" type="date" name="date" />{" "}
          <br />
          <span>Pages</span>{" "}
          <input placeholder="total pages" name="total pages" /> <br />
          <span>Dimensions</span>{" "}
          <input placeholder="total page size" name="page size" /> <br />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

the console.log() in middleware is printing undefined also the result is empty

I tried file and formdata uploading but got undefined

Comment: Do you see anything when you log `err` in `form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){...})`?

Comment: Yes this ``` err: BadRequestError: stream ended unexpectedly
    at Form.<anonymous> (/Users/name/Desktop/NextJSProjects/thebookclub/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:787:24)
    at Form.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at Form.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at finish (internal/streams/writable.js:657:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)```

Comment: If you don't try to upload a file, do you see the rest of the fields in the request when it hits the api? If so, it might be to do with the size of the file and you would need to implement a solution to chunk it up and upload it in parts.

Comment: if I do not upload files and only fields still getting the same issue, same error message ``` err: BadRequestError: stream ended unexpectedly
    at Form.<anonymous> ```

Comment: I'd advise examining the headers of your request in the browser as you send it. It seems like there could be something in there that is causing your api to expect a shorter / smaller request than you are sending.

Comment: Api headers are all normal, haven't altered them at all